# PowerBI - Count number of rows with value as table user

Tags: powerbi, dax

Not quite sure how to word this question, but I'll explain here:

I have a table that looks like this:

| User | Credits | Tasks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 100 | 5 |
| Sam | 50 | 3 |

These values are all coming from one table called `taskbin`.

I'm trying to add a column that looks up the count of rows with the user in a separate table called `qabin`.

The `qabin` table looks like this

| QAID | Submitter | QAer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | John | Sam |
| 21 | Sam | John |

Basically, I need to get a count of the number of times `John` appears in the `Submitter` field of the `qabin` table.

I could add it to the table view so it looks like this:

| User | Credits | Tasks | Submitted Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 100 | 5 | 1 |
| Sam | 50 | 3 | 1 |

I tried just adding a count of submitter to the table view, but it shows the total number of rows instead of using the correct user as listed in the table.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you Join taskbin to qabin table on the user, you can show the "User" value from taskbin and do a measure that counts the rows in qabin, in a table.  Something like this might work

Submitted Count =  CountRows('quadmin').

Comment: In my model I have the `user_name` linked to both the `Submitter` and the `QAer`. Not sure if that's problematic at all - I want to be able to switch between the two counts if needed.

Comment: To put it another way, I really just need to figure out how to get the `User` column into a dax query so I can use `CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(` where `qabin[Submitter]=UserOnWhicheverRow`

Comment: I don't know how to join the taskbin to qabin table on the user. Is that something done in the model?

Comment: In my model I have `user_name` joined to `Submitter` and `QAer` - I think that may be why I'm having issues. I tried just joining it to one, but that didn't seem to fix it, so idk.

Comment: @user1274820, Try it out with just the Join to QAer.  If you wish to have 2 joins, one will be inactive.  You will need to then select the join/Relationship you wish to use with the USERelationship in a filter.

Answer (score 1):

If these two tables are ***not*** connected for some reason

```
Column =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTX (
        FILTER ( qabin, qabin[Submitter] = CALCULATE ( MAX ( taskbin[User] ) ) ),
        qabin[Submitter]
    )
)
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Why `MAX(taskbin[User])`? Not sure I understand what that's doing

Comment: The code is passing a filtered table in `COUNTX`. `FILTER` is filtering `qabin[Submitter]` by currently visible `taskbin[User]` available  through `CALCULATE ( MAX ( taskbin[User] )` and since the code is wrapped inside `COUNTX`, it performs an iteration, i.e. picks up currently visible `taskbin[User]` and scans whole `qabin` to find match where `qabin[Submitter]=currently visible taskbin[User]` and returns count.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting identical values when looking at the count of both the Submitter and QAer field. I actually need to get both of them., It's showing that everybody pulled/posted the same amounts. I know in the example I gave they're equal, but in reality they should be different and all the numbers are identical regardless of if I look at the count of the Submitter or QAer.

Comment: I may actually have done a piss poor job of explaining my table setups TBH. The tables are actually hundreds of rows with the tasks/credits being the SUM of all the rows added up. I'm displaying them in a table that shows their sum. The QAs table also has hundreds of rows with a QAer and a Submitter listed on each row. Idk if that helps at all - sorry.

Comment: Please provide sample data representative of your issue.

Comment: Sorry - work meetings and other stuff - I will reply with the full version of tables in a bit - I appreciate the help and sorry for the delay.